# What is probility to miss at least one test?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> The probability that a teacher will give an unannounced test during any class is $\large \frac 15$. If a student is absent twice, then probability that he misses at least on test is
>
> $a) \ \frac23\ \ \       b)\ \frac45\ \ \ \ c)\ \frac7{25}\ \ \ d)\ \frac9{25} $

my trial:

probability of attending first test & missing second one $$=\frac 15\times \frac 45=\frac{4}{25}$$
probability of missing first test & attending second one   $$=\frac 45\times \frac 15=\frac{4}{25}$$
probability of missing both tests $$=\frac 15\times \frac 15=\frac 1{25}$$

hence, total probability is $$=\frac{4}{25}+\frac{4}{25}+\frac{1}{25}=\frac{9}{25}$$

i am not sure if i am correct. please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: 1. Independence hypothesis are missing. 2. The result is $$1-\left(1-\frac15\right)^2.$$